# jquery form validation by rules and alert

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I want to show alert during validation but didn't solve this issue,
My Code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').validate({ 
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                digits: false
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            pswd: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            cpswd: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#pswd"
            },
            agree: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Enter Valid Name",
                digits: "Name contains characters only"
            },
            email: {
                required: "Enter Email",
                email: "Enter Valid Email (i.e. someone@example.com)"
            },
            pswd: {
                required: "Enter Valid Password",
                minlength: "Maximum allowed length is 5 Characters"
            },
            cpswd: "Password not Matched"
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var pswd =  $("#pswd").val();
            $("#submit").click(function() {
                alert("Data Submitted Successfully!\nName : "+ name +"\nEmail : "+ email +"\nPassword : "+ pswd);
                form.submit();
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This code shows error as a text message. 
I want to show error in alert box. 

When in message i put alert like:

```
 messages: {
          name: alert('Enter Name')
},
```

then it show all alert when the page load.

Any idea how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').validate({ 
        onclick: false,//add this to your code
        rules: {
            name: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "The Name is required!"
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            alert(error.text());
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });
});
```

Working [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sagar_arora/ryoe9s9y/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `errorPlacement:` option.

`First argument`: The created error label as a jQuery object.

`Second argument`: The invalid element as a jQuery object.

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        alert(error.text());
    }
```

**CAUTION:** some browser will be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: This code shows error in alert box, But for infinite loop will occur and cant able to close alert box in chrome browser.